# Routing gives a 404 with Edge on test server but works fine locally and Chrome always works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, routes, microsoft-edge

I recently deployed a ReactJs website to our test server for business to test and noticed that going deeper in the route gives a 404 on Edge (and IE) while working fine locally and on Chrome / Firefox.

My routing is defined like this:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Header />
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={OrdersPage} />
                    <Route path="/orders/:orderReference/picking" component={OrderPickingPage}/>
                    <Route path="/orders/:orderReference/label" component={OrderLabelPage}/>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </MuiThemeProvider>);
};
```

The root always works, it's the other two that give me issue with Edge when connecting to the Test Server.

Business is overwhelmingly using Edge/IE so I *need* to support that. But, since it's not just a difference of browsers but also environments, I have the feeling it could be anything.

> Any pointers on what to look at to narrow down my search for a
>   solution?

Comment: Do you mean the route works fine locally on the IE/Edge, Chrome and Firefox browsers? But, when you deployed the project to test server, only IE/Edge isn't working, it still works well in the chrome and FireFox? If that is the case, please try to compare the request url in different browsers?

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Yep, you got it exactly right. Will see what I can find out.